# How to find the maximum and minimum value along with another column value from a table?

Tags: java, sql, h2

I've a table like this:

[image]

I want to find the maximum and minimum efficiency with their corresponding center name, group by session - like this:

[image]

I tried

```
Select max(Efficiency) as max_Efficiency, Center as max_Center, 
       min(Efficiency) as min_Efficiency, Center as min_Center 
from myTable
group by session
```

but it doesn't work, getting errors. If I leave Center ( both cases), it works, but I need the Center name as well.

Comment: What's the expected result if you add the row (1, E, 96) to your table?

Comment: A or E, any one, thanks.

Comment: I don't know h2, but you can have a sub-query that returns each session with its max and min efficiency values. Then join that result with the original table.

Comment: I thought about that, yet to try, looking for better option if there is any, Thanks @ jarlh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select session, max_efficiency, max_center, min_Efficiency, min_center from (
    select tbl.*, 
        case when tbl.session = nt.session and tbl.max_efficiency = Efficiency then nt.center end max_center,
        case when tbl.session = nt.session and tbl.max_efficiency = Efficiency then nt.center end min_center
    from (
        select  session,
                max(Efficiency) max_Efficiency,
                min(Efficiency) min_Efficiency
        from myTable
        group by session
    ) tbl
    join myTable mt
    on mt.session = tbl.session
) where (max_center is not null and min_center is not null)
```

I'm not sure about the executing time if your table has a lot of data, but this should do the trick.

Probably there might be an easier way to trim this query down.

Comment: It works, thank you so much. mytable itself is a query of big size, so the execution time higher as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query can look like:

```
select t1.Session,
       t1.max_Efficiency,
       t2.Center as max_Center,
       t1.min_Efficiency,
       t3.Center as min_Center
from (
  select Session, 
         max(Efficiency) as max_Efficiency, 
         min(Efficiency) as min_Efficiency
  from myTable
  group by Session
) as t1
inner join myTable t2 on t2.session = t1.session and t2.efficiency = t1.max_Efficiency
inner join myTable t3 on t3.session = t1.session and t3.efficiency = t1.min_Efficiency;
```

The result is

[image: SQL query result]

Comment: Thanks, it works but when there same multiple max/min answers - it shows all. Can I prevent them all but just one to show. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired result with preventing all min/max rows but one?

Answer (score 1):

With window function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select 
  t.session,
  max(case when t.maxrn = 1 then efficiency end) max_Efficiency,
  max(case when t.maxrn = 1 then center end) max_Center,
  max(case when t.minrn = 1 then efficiency end) min_Efficiency,
  max(case when t.minrn = 1 then center end) min_Center
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by session order by efficiency desc) maxrn,
    row_number() over (partition by session order by efficiency asc) minrn
  from tablename
) t
where t.maxrn = 1 or t.minrn = 1  
group by t.session
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7ad7590a6166c3da6869b9afea2ee96)(using SQL Server).

```
> session | max_Efficiency | max_Center | min_Efficiency | min_Center
> ------: | -------------: | :--------- | -------------: | :---------
>       1 |             96 | A          |             66 | B         
>       2 |             98 | C          |             32 | D
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors on my h2 database system.

Comment: H2 supports window functions: http://www.h2database.com/html/functions-window.html so I can't tell about the syntax errors.